# Why can Linux show a file name containing character '/'?

Tags: ls, filenames

The following picture is snapped in a real Linux environment.

[image: ls output showing characters similar to forward-slash (/) in a filename]

Why can Linux show a file name containing character '/'?

Comment: So what character is it?  Please update your question with the `hexdump` output.

Comment: Even if all APIs enforce filename character restrictions on write, it could be possible (but unwieldy) to edit the filename directly in the disk image. (I do not know if today's usual filesystems check filenames on read.)

Comment: @cjm，I have reverted the snapshot of vmware.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, true, but the slash in that screenshot appears very light for U+002F in a typical terminal font, suggesting that it's a different character.

Comment: @cjm It's also too short and slanted too much.

Comment: @xmllmx: That's one of the reasons why rather than (or in addition to) a picture, it's best to copy and paste the output as text.

Comment: For what it's worth: both Linux and Windows are perfectly happy to permit filenames which don't conform to the usual conventions. And even the normal command-line parser can handle many of these exceptions if you escape the character when you type it. (Or, if you're trying to reference a name that already exists, you may be able to do so by using wildcards). That might not be the case here, as others have pointed out, but I'd really suggest checking the low-level API specs before assuming it can't happen... and even then, as noted, it could be done by directly accessing filesystem structures.

Comment: Ext*  only bans two chars from filenames:  `\0` and `/`.  This is a kernel- and FS-level limitation; even if you managed to do it by mucking around with directory entries yourself, i'm about 82% certain Linux wouldn't be able to navigate to the file to open it.

Comment: @cHao, I'm about 99.9% sure Linux couldn't open a filename with a real `/` in it (created by manually editing a directory entry on disk), but it might be able to list it, which is all he's doing here.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's not a `/` character ([U+002F](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2f/index.htm)); it's some Unicode character that just looks similar.

Try

```
ls | hexdump -C
```

to see what it is.

Some possibilities are [FRACTION SLASH (U+2044)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2044/index.htm), [DIVISION SLASH (U+2215)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2215/index.htm), [MATHEMATICAL RISING DIAGONAL (U+27CB)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27cb/index.htm), and the combining solidus characters [U+0337](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0337/index.htm) and [U+0338](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0338/index.htm), but there's no way to tell which one from your screenshot.

Comment: cool...thanks, that `ls | hexdump -C` seems to be useful in a number of cases.